# Android: from which fragment did I come from?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, android-support-library

I am developing an android app in java that has this navigation structure:

```
Login-> F1->F2->F3
        |   |   |
        v   v   v
          Chart
```

Fragment `chart` should show (detail) data for (general) data of corresponding fragment `F1`, `F2` or `F3`.

**Question 1**: I prepare the visualization data in `onViewCreated` method. Manuals say that if I should get the navigation sequence there using `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` But `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();` returns 0. Can you tell me why?

**Question 2**: Can I use `fmp = this.getParentFragmentManager();` instead? This guy has correct `getBackStackEntryCount()`, which is two in case I go through `F1`.

**Question 3**: How can get the resource ID of `F1` (or `F2` or `F3`)? (Alternatively, how can I know where I came from?) In debugging mode I can see that

[image: Debugging Ids]

`getId` returns 0, but the resource id is actually concatenated with the sequence number in `getName`.

I am getting desperate here. I browsed through so many stackoverflow questions related to fragments. Most of them focus on navigation, and not to check where I came from.

Comment: Why not just pass that via the Chart fragment's arguments?

Comment: I am actually doing the navigation through `NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigate(R.id.action_F1_to_Char);` Not really creating the fragments programmatically.

Comment: You can pass arguments via `navigate()`

Comment: @ianhanniballake: thanks for the hint that I can pass arguments through navigate. I didn't know that. Any thoughts on other aspects? Is it the correct way to get to `fm` through `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`? Why does it return me an empty navigation stack?